# How to select specific folders to sync with Dropbox or OneDrive?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3, dropbox, cloud, onedrive

I've just bough a phone with Android, a Galaxy Note 3, and I have no experience with it, but I would like to have all my photo albums syncing to a cloud storage service.

I've tried OneDrive and Dropbox, however they just sync files that are located in the main camera album, if I take a picture with an App who has a folder of its own, this picture it is not synchronized. In both OneDrive and Dropbox don't see an option to select these additional folders to sync.

How can I accomplish this?